# Can I display daily data in month buckets using only excel's chart formatting?

Tags: excel, charts, formatting, bucket

I have daily sales figures that I'd like to plot on a simple linegraph.

I would like them to be shown in monthly buckets (i.e. if I sold 5€ on Jan 01 and 10€ on Jan 24, I would like to see only one data point for January with 15€ in it).

Please note that I don't want to use any supporting formula/VBA script, I want to do this using only chart formatting.

I tried setting the chart's X-axis type to "date axis" and I chose "months" as the base unit.
This *almost* works, but the line graph ends up being kind of weird. Changing the chart type to histogram doesn't help much either. The individual sales are not "piled up" like I would but, instead, they're hidden one behind the other. Stacked histogram doesn't work either.

Any clue on how I can force excel to bucketize my data using only chart formatting? This can't be that hard...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try creating a pivot chart, then grouping the dates by month (right-click a date in the pivot table, and click "Group by... Month".

Comment: Works like a charm! Only thing is, I had to group by both month and year, otherwise Jan 2011 and Jan 2011 get summed together. I didn't specify this in my question so my bad. Thanks man!

Comment: Creating a new pivot chart isn't an example of using chart formatting (and is quite difficult in itself)

Comment: Just to clarify, but to group by month in Excel 2007 you right click on a date in the chart, not the actual table. After this, it's helpful to right click on the chart and choose `Expand/Collapse > Collapse Entire Field`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to group by Years as well - hold down the Ctrl Key whilst you select the Month (both categories will then show up)