# Can I make an Excel chart group data by month (without a pivot chart)?

Tags: excel, charts

I have a basic spreadsheet with dates and amounts:

[image]

When I create a chart, Excel displays the values on a per-data-point basis. I would like the points to be displayed on a per-month basis.

[image]

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775357/can-i-display-daily-data-in-month-buckets-using-only-excels-chart-formatting/9775943#9775943), but without a pivot chart.

Comment: Do you have the capacity to add columns to the data? If so, you could add a "Month" column next to your "Created (UTC)" column which would simply use the `MONTH` function in Excel. Then by using `SUMIF` (or `SUMIFS` if you're using multiple years) you can produce a summary table by month. Then graph that instead?

Answer (score 0):

First I made another column which extracted just the month out of the dates:

```
=MONTH(<date cell>)+((YEAR(<date cell>)-2015)*12)
```

Then using @asongtoruin's suggestion, I ended up making a series of cells for each month

Eg:

```
 =SUMIF(<range of months>, 0,<range of values>)

 =SUMIF(<range of months>, 1,<range of values>)

 =SUMIF(<range of months>, 2,<range of values>)
```

I then had a series of month-only data:

[image]

Which I could then make a chart for:

[image]